# Where to integrate code generation in dev-server command

Tags: typescript, angular-devkit

We are using the `dev-server` command from [`@angular-devkit/build-angular`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular) to run our TypeScrpt/Angular application locally on a development server with live reloading. This works quite well - whenever a file is changed, the compilation process is triggered and the updated application is served.

Now, we would like to integrate some code generation - that is, call some tools that generate a bunch of TypeScript files, which should then be included in the compilation. This should happen every time the build runs, obviously right before TypeScript compilation, while at the same time in such a way that the regenerated code files do not trigger an additional build/serve cycle due to containing changes.

So far, we have managed to auto-run our generation command, but either just *after* the build (i.e. too late), or right before it, but in the latter case, the build always appears to repeat once, which unnecessarily prolongs waiting time.

**Is this possible with `dev-server` or do we have to create a modified version thereof?**

Comment: can you plz post some code?